# Laravel User Eloquent model returning null when record exists

Tags: php, laravel, twitter, eloquent, laravel-socialite

Hair-pulling time.

I have implemented a callback for Laravel Socialite. It's running `User::where` against the Twitter user ID, but is always returning null despite the fact that there is a record in the database that matches.

Therefore it always tries to create a new user, leading to an error of this kind:

`QueryException in Connection.php line 673:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry...`

Here's the callback function. `$twitterUser` is the incoming user record from Socialite. I have tried explicitly using `\App\User\` in the function, but to no avail.

```
private function findOrCreateUser( $twitterUser )
{
  $user = User::where( 'twitter_id', $twitterUser->id )->first();

  if ($user)
  {
    return $user;
  }

  return User::create([
    'name'        => $twitterUser->name,
    'handle'      => $twitterUser->nickname,
    'twitter_id'  => $twitterUser->id,
    'avatar'      => $twitterUser->avatar_original
  ]);
}
```

If I run the code elsewhere in the app, the user shows up fine, and if I try `php artisan tinker` followed by `\App\User::where('twitter_id', 123456789)->first()` I get a result:

```
=> App\User {#663
 id: 3,
 name: "Steve Jones",
 handle: "SteveJonesGtr",
 twitter_id: 123456789,
 avatar: "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/whatever/bC0RLl-3.jpeg",
 created_at: "2016-04-20 11:41:39",
 updated_at: "2016-04-20 11:41:39",
```

}

EDIT: If I change the `where` clause to this, it works:

`$user = User::where( 'handle', $twitterUser->nickname )->first();`

But I can't see why it won't return a result for this:

`$user = User::where( 'twitter_id', $twitterUser->id )->first();`

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you do the reverse condition;

  if (!$user)
  {
    
    return User::create([
    'name'        => $twitterUser->name,
    'handle'      => $twitterUser->nickname,
    'twitter_id'  => $twitterUser->id,
    'avatar'      => $twitterUser->avatar_original
  ]);

  }
 return $user;

Comment: If you `dd($user)` just after the `User::where` ? What prints?

Comment: @PietroLerro It just prints 'null'. That's the core of the problem. The DB definitely has the record.

Comment: @KreshnikHasanaj - exactly the same because at that point, $user is always null. So that condition (!$user) is always met and I'm back with the duplicate entry error :(

Comment: @raffjones can you post more code, on how the whole routine looks like.

Comment: What if you do a `dd($twitterUser);` in your function, see what you are passing through and if it is actually being casted to the object.

Comment: @TutelageSystems - it's exactly what I expect - the correct object

Answer (score -2):

you are searching for  12345678 not 123456789 thats your problem. your missing the 9 at the end

Comment: That was just a typo in the question but thanks for pointing it out. I replaced my real Twitter ID with a fake one. It's not the issue.

Comment: great i thought you literally copied it thats all :)